# How to use an existing repository while commiting to your own one

Tags: github, repository

I'm in the process of doing a react course. I want to be using the existing course repository and fetch (not sure if this is the word) changes from there. I also want to show that I do daily work on my github account and commit changes to my github. How can I achieve that?

Answer (score 0):

1. Go to original repository on right you will see fork button, click on it.

   This will create a copy of the original repository.
2. Go to your repositories in github, you will see the a newly created repo with same name as the original. Open that new repo add click on clone (green button).
3. Copy the https link that pop-up.
4. Open terminal, go to your desired folder.  cd path/to/folder
5. git clone

After this point feel free to create new files. When your are done

1. git add .
2. git commit -m "My daily update note"
3. git push

Comment: it should be git clone https link you copied earlier : ie git clone https://github.com/someone/somerepo.git